# Typescript: Argument of type is not assignable to parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```
export type APIResponseType = string | number;

class QueueRequest {
    private readonly requests: Record<string, MyRequest<APIResponseType>[]> = {};

    public addRequest<T extends APIResponseType>(request: MyRequest<T>) {
        if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.requests, request.url)) {
            this.requests[request.url] = [];
        }
        this.requests[request.url].push(request);
    }
}


const queueRequest = new QueueRequest();

class MyRequest<TResponse> {
    readonly url: string;
    private onSuccess: (response: TResponse) => void;

    constructor(url: string, onSuccess: (response: TResponse) => void) {
        this.url = url;
        this.onSuccess = onSuccess;
    }
}

function updateState(request: MyRequest<string>) {
    makeRequest(request);

}

function updateProperties(request: MyRequest<number>) {
    makeRequest(request);

}

function makeRequest<T extends APIResponseType>(request: MyRequest<T>) {
    queueRequest.addRequest(request)
}
```

For above code I got an error on Line 14:
1.

```
Argument of type 'MyRequest<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyRequest<APIResponseType>'.
Type 'APIResponseType' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'APIResponseType' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'APIResponseType'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'APIResponseType'.
```

By changing the function argument from `APIResponseType` to `any` on Line 4 there are no errors produced. Any idea how to limit the scope of possible options instead of using `any`?
The `QueueRequest` should contain different types of `MyRequests`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would use generics [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/mbKAdW).  What, specifically, about generics makes you say they are "probably not the best option here"?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz for the solution. While it works as expected, I have come to another issue.  I added additional logic and come to yet another problem.
I have updated the question with additional code.

Comment: You have used MyRequest<APIResponseType>[]> in line 4 while not using [] in the next line?

Comment: It's not generally appropriate to change the scope of the question in response to a suggested answer.  I'm concerned that if I try to address the current version of your question, you'll just change it again to ask about the next problem you run into.  Could you change the question back to its original form and post a new question if you have a new question?  Or, if you want to keep this question in the current form, can you commit not to change its scope further if someone answers it?

Comment: @jzalc. This is the final scope of the answer